# How to resolve this npm run watch error in laravel/vue?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I was trying to run an npm run watch in console and I got this error.

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pPV5.png)

```
× Mix
Compiled with some errors in 50.24ms

ERROR in ./resources/js/app.js 9:0-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './App.vue' in 'C:\Users\kodione\laravel-vue-exercise\resources\js'

webpack compiled with 1 error
```

Here is my app.js code.

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');

 import App from './App.vue';
 import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';
 import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
 import axios from 'axios';
 import { routes } from './routes';

 Vue.use(VueRouter);
 Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);

 const router = new VueRouter({
     mode: 'history',
     routes: routes
});

 const app = new Vue({
     el: '#app',
     router: router,
     render: h => h(App),
 });
```

I am completely new to this so I am opened for critique.

[This is the folder structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pPV5.png)

Comment: Maybe it's simple file folder error on : import App from './App.vue'; do you have this file in the correct file foldering

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message in text form and your attempts to resolve that error

Comment: Also specify the version of Laravel you are using.

Comment: It's a laravel 8 I have absolutely no idea how to fix it. I am only working on laravel for past 3 days and couldn't find many solutions. I will edit the post to include the error message in text form.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I found it. If your folder structure is same as in the given screenshot, Then It should be inside the components, That is

```
import App from './components/App.vue';
```

This should fix the error.